# Existence of the limit $\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_0^R \frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, proof-explanation, improper-integrals

I must prove the existence of the limit $$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_0^R \frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx$$ The justification given is as follows: for all $R>\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $$\begin{align}\int_0 ^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx-\frac{\cos R}{R}-\int_{\pi/2}^R \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\; dx\\&\to \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx -\int_{\pi/2}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\; dx\end{align}$$ for $R\to \infty$ having used the Lebesgue Theorem.

1. Why does it have to be $R>\pi/2$?
2. Where was Lebesgue's theorem used?

Comment: Which Lebesgue theorem are you referring to? Notice that in each interval $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$ the integrand changes its sign and the area in each integral decreases and approaches zero. What happens to an alternating series with each term's absolute value decreasing to zero?

Comment: 1. It doesn't really, only needed $R>0$.  But I guess that is what you want to make $\int_{\pi/2}^R \dots$ appears natural. 2. To conclude $\int^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ exists and is the limit of the last integral before last equality.

Comment: @user10354138 This comment could be an answer.

Comment: @ApocalypseDominated convergence theorem

Comment: @Apocalypse I think you should have asked "What happens to the sum of an alternating series..." instead. And I agree that that seems the more natural way to show convergence.

Comment: As is commented, the answer can be 
$$ 
\int_0 ^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\ dx=\int_0^{d}\frac{\sin x}{x}\ dx-\frac{\cos u}{u}\mid_d^R-\int_{d}^R \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\ dx
$$

with any $d>0$ you like. Why is this step necessary? If you simply write

$$ 
\int_0 ^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\ dx= -\frac{\cos u}{u}|_0^R-\int_{0}^R \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\ dx
$$
 , then $\int_{0}^R \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\ dx$ will be divergent as $0$ is a "pole", and $-\frac{\cos u}{u}$ is not defined at $u=0$. And I do not think Dominated Convergence Theorem is involved in the solution.